# SQL Server decimal point problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table in SQL Server with a column  `ABC Decimal(12, 10)`

Whenever I save zero to this column, it automatically formated to 0E-10.

why cant it show `0.0000000000` instead of `0E-10` while fetching from my apps.?

How to prevent this? Can someone help. Thanks

Comment: First of all - I can't reproduce this (SQL Server 2008 R2). Which **version** of SQL Server are you using?? Also: **where and when** do you see this `0E-10` ? When you select in SQL Server Mgmt Studio? From you app?? Furthermore: the decimal value is stored as a decimal (numeric) value - if you see a certain string representation of it, that doesn't mean it's stored that way - it's just shown to you that way. The decimal is just a decimal is just a decimal - it doesn't have any *formatting* while stored.

Comment: thanks ..am using sqlserver2005. Its showing like so in my apps as well as DB visualizer.How to resolve this.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (ABC DECIMAL(12,10))
INSERT INTO @Test(ABC) VALUES(0.0)

SELECT * FROM @Test
```

What output do you get??

I get :

```
ABC
0.0000000000
```

You're barking up the wrong tree - I don't see this as a SQL Server issue - you need to check what your apps are doing with that value...

Answer (score 0):

You can only get 0E-10 in client tools, in client code, or perhaps with `float`.

*Never* with decimal

Do you have a view with a CAST somewhere?